# When FBIDE will be released?

Tags: facebook, hacklang, fbide

FB guys on some talk you said, that it will be in summer 14', but now already spring 15'. Do you have any plans?

Currently one big blocker to move to Hack language is missing plugins for popular **free** IDEs like eclipse/netbeans/other (atom with it's "code completion" is not a good IDE).

Comment: See https://code.facebook.com/videos/1483231821892511/introduction-to-fbide-hack-dev-day/

Comment: ps: Atom guys, I know, you are working hard on autocomplete-plus. When it will be finished I will be first in queque to you :)

Comment: Atom can work with Hacklang completion with context! See https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4920#issuecomment-76521805 When hh_client will have PHP too — then problem is gone. See https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4806

Answer (score 1):

FB guy responded:

> IDE work is still ongoing internally. Things have just been taking a
>   lot longer than expected, but it's still being worked on, and
>   continuing to get closer. Sorry it's taken so so much longer than we
>   expected :(
>
> I'm going to close this issue since there's not really anything here
>   to track.

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4920#issuecomment-76587213